# What to do when I get the unauthorized error in Parse Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, swift2, back4app

I'm using the blank app Parse download and back4app. I put the client and application id on `AppDelegate` and run the app, but I get the following error:

> "2016-07-26 11:08:29.681 ParseStarterProject-Swift[1464:107722]
>   [Error]: unauthorized (Code: 0, Version: 1.12.0) 2016-07-26
>   11:08:29.682 ParseStarterProject-Swift[1464:107719] [Error]: Failed to
>   run command eventually with error: Error Domain=Parse Code=0
>   "unauthorized" UserInfo={error=unauthorized,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=unauthorized, temporary=0}"

ViewController is empty

**AppDelegate:**

```
import UIKit

import Parse

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

//--------------------------------------
// MARK: - UIApplicationDelegate
//--------------------------------------

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Enable storing and querying data from Local Datastore.
    // Remove this line if you don't want to use Local Datastore features or want to use cachePolicy.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
     Parse.setApplicationId("ciBn93EohqEq7WLJEAByrrVFfR6B3Fu98UJgRteY",clientKey: "KHKJgfJhSLAktjqmKHRhlaUtBhtzZELsdwexpIdf")

    PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()

    let defaultACL = PFACL();

    // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
    defaultACL.publicReadAccess = true

    PFACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser: true)

    if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
        // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
        // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
        // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.

        let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
        let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
        var noPushPayload = false;
        if let options = launchOptions {
            noPushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil;
        }
        if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || noPushPayload) {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
        }
    }

    return true
}

//--------------------------------------
// MARK: Push Notifications
//--------------------------------------

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()

    PFPush.subscribeToChannelInBackground("") { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) in
        if succeeded {
            print("ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.\n");
        } else {
            print("ParseStarterProject failed to subscribe to push notifications on the broadcast channel with error = %@.\n", error)
        }
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    if error.code == 3010 {
        print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.\n")
    } else {
        print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@\n", error)
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You should never publish your application ID and client keys.  You should regenerate new keys immediately.

Comment: Thanks, but is just a test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I find what should you do,it's just change
>
> This

```
 Parse.setApplicationId("APP_ID",clientKey: "CLIENT_KEY")
```

> With this

```
let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration{
        $0.applicationId = "APP_ID"
        $0.clientKey = "CLIENT_KEY"
        $0.server = "https://parseapi.back4app.com/"
    }
```

The server address still the same

Answer (score 0):

I think something must be wrong with you appid and client key.

Comment: This might be better suited as a comment.  Can you please elaborate on how this answers the question?